# how to set bash window colors based on project/folder?

Tags: bash

In Mac Terminal (using bash)  I work on multiple projects at the same time in different tabs... is there any way to have the tab's window color customized based upon the folder (eg project)?

Specifically:

```
$
# window starts default theme

$ cd project1
# window changes to different theme or at least BG color

$ cd ../project2
# window changes to yet another different theme or at least BG color
```

Is there for example a concept of a 'local' bash settings file that gets read if you cd into a folder?

Comment: See :[Is there a folder-specific .bashrc or .bash_profile?](https://superuser.com/q/915703/340330)

Answer (score 0):

You could create shell functions for `cd`, `pushd` and `popd` (I think these are the only commands which change the working directory), in the following way:

```
cd()
{
  command cd $1
  [[ -f .bashrc_for_this_folder ]] && . .bashrc_for_this_folder
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom script using Mac script editor ( Applications/Utilities )

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set current settings of window 1 to settings set "novel"
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    set current settings of window 1 to settings set "grass"
end tell
```

then open your .bash_profile  then create a function based on the project name for eg:-

```
project1(){
osascript ~/Documents/scripts/bg_novel.scpt
cd  "path to project folder"  
}
project2(){
osascript ~/Documents/scripts/bg_grass.scpt
cd  "path to project folder" 
}
```

re-open your Terminal and just call the function via entering function name on Terminal like Poject1

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1188772/mac-command-to-change-the-background-color-in-a-terminal